Sending Images in PNG format to ant media server
Problem description
I have an android App. It produces bytearrays and converts them to PNG image. I need to send these images to ant media server as a stream.
Attempt to resolve
Searching send png images to ant media serveron SO yielded me 0 results.
I looked up the ant documentation - but this only gives an example of a surface view that sends data from a camera.
Question
Please help me to formulate a solution. I have no idea where to start. Thank you
